# CSS syntax questions

Tags: css

```
.features img{...}
```

I understand `.features` is custom CSS class and div is HTML element. But I don't understand what kind of relationship this syntax will build between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax doesn't build any relationship between the `.features` class and a div.

The style that you provided is styling any child `<img>` tag contained within a `.features` class.

Both of these would be valid and apply the given style to the image:

```
<div class="features">
    <img src="myImg.png" />
</div>
```

and

```
<table class="features">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="myImg.png" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you wanted to specify that your class was only applicable to divs, you would need to change the declaration to:

```
div.features img { }
```

Comment: This syntax defines scope in other words, for the element specified at the end of this definition. Can I have nested scope definition or it's limited only by two items?

Comment: You can increase the scope how you wish: `div.features div span a img` would select an image inside an `<a>` tag in a nested div within a div with the class features. There are no limits :)

Comment: You can definitely nest them. One extremely common use of nesting is styling menus that are driven by an unordered list.